# Fresh Rails 6.0.0 breaks after doing `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

(Learning Rails 6)

I have a fresh Ruby 2.6.3 and Rails 6.0.0 setup.

Started out a fresh rails project with

`rails new flix && cd flix`

Running `rails s` worked just fine

Then I wanted to run

```
rails g controller movies
```

but it complaining..

Tried to do a `spring stop` (as suggested on stackoverflow) - that did not work. Then I did `bundle install` and the generate contoller worked.

But now the `rails s` won't work at all..‍♂️

It's saying something about

```
`require': incompatible library version - /Users/norfeldt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
```

and a lot of others `LoadErrors`.

What to do? (seems a bit early to break it all)

Comment: Does it work when you run `bin/rails g controller movies` or `bundle exec rails g controller movies`?

Comment: Have you tried doing `gem update --system`?

Comment: @fphilipe `bundle exec rails g controller movies` didn't work (before doing the `bundle install`). Didn't try the `bin/rails ..`

Comment: @mutantkeyboard no I did not try that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the following

```
gem uninstall -aIx
```

and then

```
bundle install
```

now it works.. (but I have to do `bundle install` in other Rails projects on my computer)